# Not able to run the training job in google AI platform

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, google-cloud-ml

> Errno 2 No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-req-build-7ii0_y8n/setup.py'

Getting the above when running object detection model in Google Cloud ML engine.

Tried installing all the required packages for training the model in Google cloud ML engine

https://github.com/pkulzc/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md#coco-api-installation

I am not able to run my training due to this error

> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 454, in open
>   buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
>   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-req-build-kb73s3vo/setup.py'

Comment: Were you following the instructions on this page?  https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_cloud.md

Comment: yes i followed the same. i am not getting proper support from google also as they are redirecting me to use AutoML ! @dizcology

Comment: Depending on your use case AutoML's Object Detection service might be indeed sufficient: https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/

That being said, let me look into running a training job on AI Platform (formerly ML Engine).

Comment: I followed the steps on the installation page (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md) then the steps on the "running on cloud page" (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_cloud.md) and did not have any issue (except for one minor issue) starting a training job on AI Platform Training.  One thing that might make a difference is that I am using python 2.7 when I installed packages locally.  Could you share more details on the step where you got the error?

Comment: i run the job in google cloud shell instance. i faced these issues. its getting failed whenever i am running. i used all the packages and versions given by the cloud shell. (tensorflow - 1.13 and python default -2.7. i also able to see python 3.5 over there)

Comment: i am using object detection API for training the dataset in google cloud https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection

Comment: I see - I had not tried to do the same in cloud shell.  I think the recommended steps outlined in the repo ask you to (1) follow the steps in this first link (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md) to install locally on your computer, then (2) follow the steps in this second link (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_cloud.md) to submit a training job to Google Cloud AI Platform Training.

Comment: yes @dizcology. i tried that way too. installed locally and submitted on google cloud. but i could not able to get it start training

Comment: In the case when you installed locally, did all the installation steps succeed?  Were you able to create a training job on google cloud but the job failed?

Comment: yes its getting failed @dizcology

Comment: Was the `No such file or directory` error from trying to train as a submitted job or from cloud shell?

Comment: yes the above error coming when i am running the training job in cloud shell @dizcology

Comment: It appears to be some sort of dependency issue on cloud shell, but the workflow I suggested above (installing locally and then submitting the job, not using cloud shell at all) should work.  Do you mind trying it?

Comment: @dizcology i tried all the ways. it is not at all working. it seems like ml engine changed some back end configurations

Comment: When you installed object detection API locally (not on cloud shell), did the "test the installation" step succeed?  (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md#testing-the-installation)

Since you mentioned that the "No such file or directory" error was from cloud shell, what was the error you got from ML Engine?

Comment: yes it do succeed @dizcology

Comment: Please share the error you got from ML Engine (not cloud shell).